# Permutative SQLite view which returns too many rows to be called without where clause

Tags: sqlite, view

I am working on a C++ program backed by an SQLite database.  The database contains tables for documents, elements of documents, and document boundaries (which is the set of document elements which lie on a document boundary).  The documents are created at runtime.

The program supports a basic operation to merge documents, which creates a new document with the union of the elements from the source documents, and a new boundary whose elements are chosen from the source documents' boundaries according to a set of rules that differ according to different merge types.  The rules are also stored in a table.

As I worked on the database schema, I realized I could create a SQLite view which joins the rules table to the boundaries table and produces the list of all the boundary elements which would be in the result if you joined each document to each other document according to each merge plan.

Clearly this view would return too many results to be run directly; on the order of `O(D*D*B*M)` where `D=count(Documents), B=count(Boundary elements), and M=count(MergeTypes)`.  However I *think* that if you used the view in another query with a where clause filtering the results to 2 documents and 1 merge type, SQLite would not create the entire view result, just the results which pertain to the where clause.

Is this a correct assumption?  Or will the mere existence of a view with a potentially enormous result set create problems with the database?

Comment: After getting the permutative view working which shows the potential result of "what if" any two documents are merged, I realized that with a recursive CTE I could create a view that will show the potential result of any *tree* of merge operations.  The natural input to such a query is a self-referencing table describing an expression tree.  However once you have this input table, the problem posed in the original question goes away because the view is only exploring the combinations "asked about" by rows existing in the expression tree table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are queries that must be computed completely before their results can be read (e.g., ones using ORDER BY).
But if possible, the query optimizer tries to merge the view into the outer query, i.e., to [flatten](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening) it.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned "ORDER BY" because during development I often put an order by in my views to make it easier to manually verify the results.  If I had not read your answer and accidentally left that in the view after I was done developing it, I might have had problems!

Comment: There are other bad things; see the list in the link.